# how to draw my custom view on GridView?

Tags: android, view

I have created a custom view for displaying a letter in a fill circle. For example the circle is filled with GREEN and the letter on it is RED.

Now I want to draw several that custom views in a GridView. For example if the GridView is 5x5, you'll see 25 that custom views on the screen (and maybe each custom view has different letter)

Anyone know this?
Thank you for your help

Edit #1:
This is my custom view

```
package com.hoangtrinh.paintmycustomview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class LetterView extends View {

    private int letterBackgroundColor, letterColor;
    private String letterText;
    private Paint myLetterPaint;

    public int getLetterBackgroundColor() {
        return letterBackgroundColor;
    }

    public void setLetterBackgroundColor(int letterBackgroundColor) {
        this.letterBackgroundColor = letterBackgroundColor;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    public int getLetterColor() {
        return letterColor;
    }

    public void setLetterColor(int letterColor) {
        this.letterColor = letterColor;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    public String getLetterText() {
        return letterText;
    }

    public void setLetterText(String letterText) {
        this.letterText = letterText;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    public LetterView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        AttributeSet attrs = null;
        myLetterPaint = new Paint();
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.LetterView, 0, 0);
        try {
            letterBackgroundColor = a.getInteger(
                    R.styleable.LetterView_letterBackgroundColor, 0);
            letterColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.LetterView_letterColor, 0);
            letterText = a.getString(R.styleable.LetterView_letterText);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    public LetterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        myLetterPaint = new Paint();
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.LetterView, 0, 0);
        try {
            letterBackgroundColor = a.getInteger(
                    R.styleable.LetterView_letterBackgroundColor, 0);
            letterColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.LetterView_letterColor, 0);
            letterText = a.getString(R.styleable.LetterView_letterText);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int viewWidthHalf = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int viewHeightHalf = this.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        int radius = 0;
        if(viewWidthHalf>viewHeightHalf)
            radius=viewHeightHalf-10;
        else
            radius=viewWidthHalf-10;
        myLetterPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        myLetterPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        myLetterPaint.setColor(letterBackgroundColor);
        canvas.drawCircle(viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, radius, myLetterPaint);
        myLetterPaint.setColor(letterColor);
        myLetterPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        myLetterPaint.setTextSize(50);
        canvas.drawText(letterText, viewWidthHalf, viewHeightHalf, myLetterPaint);
    }

}
```

This is my custom view adapter

```
package com.hoangtrinh.paintmycustomview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class LetterViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<LetterView> customViews = new ArrayList<LetterView>();
    private Context context;

    public LetterViewAdapter(List<LetterView> customViews, Context context) {
        this.customViews = customViews;
        this.context = context;
   }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return customViews.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return customViews.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
           // You can construct your view here.
            LetterView letterView = new LetterView(context);
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
            layout.addView(letterView);
            return layout;

            // or return your custom views array element
            // return customViews.get(position);
        } else {
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

This is MainActivity

```
package com.hoangtrinh.paintmycustomview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GridView myGridView;
    static final String[] LETTER_CASE = new String[] { 
        "A", "B","C", "D" };
    List<LetterView> customViews = new ArrayList<LetterView>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        myGridView.setAdapter(new LetterViewAdapter(customViews, this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my custom view (letter.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.hoangtrinh.paintmycustomview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.hoangtrinh.paintmycustomview.LetterView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:letterBackgroundColor="#00FFFF"
        custom:letterColor="#FF0000"
        custom:letterText="H" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally this is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="40dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom adapter for your GridView and returning your custom view from it's getView method ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue ? I am also trying to do something similar to this and I end up drawing the same view again and again !! Here's my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864228/andrioid-unable-to-re-create-canvas-view-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own adapter class. Extend [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class and override (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView (int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup) to return your custom view.

Example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

```
   public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<CustomView> customViews = new ArrayList<CustomView>();
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(List<CustomView> customViews, Context context) {
        this.customViews = customViews;
        this.context = context;
   }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return customViews.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return customViews.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
           // You can construct your view here.
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setText("" + position);
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.btn_star));
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
            layout.addView(textView);
            layout.addView(imageView);
            return layout;

            // or return your custom views array element
            // return customViews.get(position);
        } else {
            return convertView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't now how to override the getView method. Sorry but I am really a beginner with android. I read a tutorial but they use ImageView instead
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
  imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
  imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
  return imageView;
 }

Comment: You can return any view in getView method. Just return your custom view.